# Kohana 3 Pagination & Route question

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

This is a bit cryptic, especially on day 1.  Could use some help if you dont mind.  Controller is search, on action_query($search_term)

So right now its /search/query/some query?page=1 (this is without a route)
Need to get it setup in this format..

/search/some query/1
1 being the page with pagination

```
        $pagination = Pagination::factory(array(
            'current_page'      => array('source' => 'route', 'key' => 'page'),
            'total_items'       => $count,
            'items_per_page'    => 100,
            'view'              => 'pagination/basic',  
        ));
```

With Route

```
 Route::set('page', '<controller>/<action>/<search_term>(/<page>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'action' => 'query',
        'search_term' => '[a-zA-Z0-9 ]',
        'controller' => 'search',
        'action' => 'page',
        'page' => '1',
    )
);
```

Comment: What is your error? Wrong URLs? And `'search_term' => '[a-zA-Z0-9 ]'` is a regex, not a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a pagination working and my route looks like:

```
Route::set('comments', 'welcome/index(/<page>)', array('page' => '[0-9]+'))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index'
));
```

Also, I think you are missing a parameter when creating the paginator, which is:

```
'uri_segment'    => 'page', // pass a string as uri_segment to trigger former 'label' functionality.
```